# SSL enabled URL (https://localhost:44301/) not working for ASP.Net MVC site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl

I'm having a problem to run SSL enabled ASP.Net MVC site. I tried to create an ASP.NET based MVC webpage. I followed following steps:

1. I've enabled the SSL property to **True**.
2. Copied the SSL URL (in my case it was localhost:44301).
3. In Solution Explorer, right clicked the SSLMVCTestApp and select Properties.
4. Select the Web tab.
5. Paste the SSL URL into the Project Url box, then click Create Virtual Directory.
6. Saved the project and Run the project.

The Browser is opened with URL containing https, however no page is shown and rather it shows the message : "This webpage is not available".

However, for non HTTPS url it is working. Can anyone please guide me to resolve this issue. I need to run Https enabled URL from my apps.

Thanks & Best Regards,

Ahmed

Comment: what version of Visual Studio are you using? Does it include Cassini or IIS Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to do the steps 3 to 5.
Just run the project and open your url `https://localhost:44301` in your browser.

And now, because of your action, maybe you need to remove the virtual directory you created in your ApplicationHost.config file

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Now the app runs in https URL. Now I want to move to next step. I'm trying to create a Facebook app using default Facebook Template for Asp.Net MVC. I'm registered  in developers.facebook.com and created an app. I've used the App ID/App Secret and Namespace and configured the web.config file of my MVCApp with these settings. Now if I run the app it logs in to facebook. But after that it generates following error

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Now the app runs in https URL. Now I want to move to next step. I'm trying to create a Facebook app using default Facebook Template for Asp.Net MVC. I'm registered  in developers.facebook.com and created an app. I've used the App ID/App Secret and Namespace and configured the web.config file of my MVCApp with these settings. Now if I run the app it logs in to facebook. But after that it generates following error

Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not convert string to integer: public_profile. Path 'data[0].permission', line 1, position 39.