# MVC.NET Site SSL - Site Can't Produce a secure connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, ssl

I would like to add SSL to my project and wanted to check that everything still works before I deploy. At first I had the same problem as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604117/ssl-enabled-url-https-localhost44301-not-working-for-asp-net-mvc-site) so I followed the instructions in the answers and then got this error:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection

I also have this in my global.asax file:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
```

Am I missing something?
Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to get it to work. The problem was that Visual Studio wasn't generating the certificate.

If you come across this problem, I solved it by going to Add/Remove Programs and chose the Repair option on IIS Express.